# React class component. Todo app. How to store data with localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'd like to store todo data with localStorage so that it won't disappear after refreshing the page.
I used React class component when started creating.

I've added 'handleFormSubmit' and 'ComponentDidMount' methods.

1. nothing stores in localStorage when I type todo and choose date.
2. get an error in ComponentDidMount with
   Line 'const result = localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];'
   :SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
3. how can I set and get items?

It would be really appreciated if I could get help.
I'd like to make this app really work.

```
import React from "react"
import TodoItem from "./components/TodoItem"
import todosData from "./components/todosData"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            todos: todosData,
            //setTodos: todosData,
            newItem: "",
            deadline: "",
            editing: false
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.addTodo = this.addTodo.bind(this)
        this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this)
        this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this)
        this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this)
        this.updateDeadline = this.updateDeadline.bind(this)
        this.updateInputDeadline = this.updateInputDeadline.bind(this)
        this.editItem = this.editItem.bind(this)
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(id) {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map((todo) => {
          if (todo.id === id) {
            return { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed };
          } else {
            return todo;
          }
        });
        return { todos: updatedTodos };
      });
    }

    addTodo(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const newTodo = {
        id: this.state.todos.length + 1,
        text: this.state.newItem,  
        completed: false,
        deadline: this.state.deadline
      }
      const newTodos = this.state.todos.concat([newTodo]);
      this.setState({
        todos: newTodos
      })
    }

    updateInput(value, id) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
        const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map((todo) => {
          if(todo.id === id) {
            return {...todo, text: value}
          }else {
            return todo;
          }
        })
        return {todos: updatedTodos}
      })
    }

    updateInputDeadline(value, id) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
        const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map((todo) => {
          if(todo.id === id) {
            console.log(value, id);
            return {...todo, deadline: value}
          }else {
            return todo;
          }
        })
        return {todos: updatedTodos}
      })
    }

    updateItem(e) {
      this.setState({
        newItem: e.target.value
      })
    }

    updateDeadline(e) {
      this.setState({
        deadline: e.target.value
      })
    }

    deleteItem(id){
    const filteredItems= this.state.todos.filter(item =>
      item.id!==id); 
      this.setState({
      todos: filteredItems
    })
  }

  editItem(id) {
    this.setState({
      editing: id
    })
  }

  handleFormSubmit() {
    const { todo, deadline } = this.state;
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todo));
    localStorage.setItem('deadline', deadline);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const localData = localStorage.getItem('todo');
    const result = localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
    const deadlineData = localStorage.getItem('deadline');
    this.setState({ result, deadlineData });

  }

    render() {
        const todoItems = this.state.todos.map
        (item =>
          <TodoItem
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          addTodo={this.addTodo}
          deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
          updateInput={this.updateInput}
          updateInputDeadline={this.updateInputDeadline}
          isEdited={this.state.editing === item.id}
          editItem={this.editItem}
        />)


        return (
          <div className="todo-list">
          <Timer />

          <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
            <div className="add-todo">
              <label>Add an item...</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="todo"
                placeholder="Type item here..."
                value={this.state.newItem}
                onChange={this.updateItem}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="date">
              <label htmlFor="deadline">Deadline</label>
              <input
                type="date" id="start" name="deadline"
                min="2021-01-01"
                max="2024-12-31"
                value={this.state.deadline}
                onChange={this.updateDeadline}
              />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" onClick={this.addTodo}>Add to the list</button>
          </form>

            {todoItems.length === 0 ? <p>No items</p> : null}

            <div className="todoitems">
              {todoItems}
            </div>

          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Can you check what returns in line `result` in from this line `const result = localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [] `?

Comment: @2u4u since I get the error, I changed it to ```const result = localData ? localData : [] ``` and used console.log. It logged out 'Object { result: "laundry" }'.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you press the button, there are two events that you are trying to call - addTodo and handleFormSubmit. Since you are calling `e.preventDefault()` in addTodo, the submit event is never called. You could do all of the actions you need in one of the methods.
2. My guess is that you are either trying to JSON.parse an array instead of an object, or the value of `todo` is undefined. You are trying to get `todo` out of `this.state`, but you only have `todos` in your state, so it might be a typo. The same goes for `deadline`.
3. You are doing the setting and getting correctly. You could actually get data from localStorage even when you are first setting the state in constructor. But the componendDidMount approach you tried is also good.

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        const cachedTodos = localStorage.getItem("todo")
        this.state = {
            todos: cachedTodos ?? todosData,
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Aidam1. I'd like to put all in 1 method. addTodo(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const { todos, deadline, id, completed } = this.state;
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify([...todos]));
      localStorage.setItem('deadline', deadline);
    } However, this does not return todo item on the list even when I click 'add' button. How can I make it work?

Comment: In this.state.todos, you have an array of all todos right? So you can just save this array to localStorage. 
`addTodo(e) { e.preventDefault();
const newTodos = ... /* put logic for updating todos here */
this.setState({todos: newTodos}, () => {
 localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify({todos: [this.state.todos]}));
}} `